# Hey, I am trying to create one on one chat with android, nodejs , mysql db

Tags: node.js, chat

> I am working with ws library in nodejs. I don't understanded how can I send a message for specfic client here is my code.
> In my code, When I get a connection from a client I get from the url the client id and receiver_id,then i am reading from the db, all their messages. right now i am sending a broadcast to all connceted users and of course it's not right.

1. How can i send data just for the client who just login?.
2. When a message is recived how can I send to the recived  client? what if he is not connected?
   3)My logic is like this: First a user login he gets all his messages with the second user. then every time he send a data, the server get it, the server will insert the data and try to send it to other client.

   const SocketServer = require('websocket').server
   const http = require('http')
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
   var mysql = require('mysql');

   ```
    var connection_sql = mysql.createConnection({
    host            : '*',
    user            : '*',
    password        : '*',
    database        : '*'
   ```

   });

   ```
    connection_sql.connect(function(err) {
   ```

   if (err) throw err;
   console.log("Connected!");
   });

   const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {})
   server.listen(3000, ()=>{
   console.log("Listening on port 3000...")
   })

   wsServer = new SocketServer({httpServer:server})

   const connections = []

> **New connection request was recived**

```
wsServer.on('request', (req) => {
    const connection = req.accept()
    connection.userid = req.resourceURL.query.email_sender_id
    connection.receiver_id = req.resourceURL.query.email_receiver_id

    var sql = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE((email_sender_id=? AND email_receiver_id=?) OR (email_sender_id=? AND email_receiver_id=?))"
    values = [userid,receiver_id,receiver_id,userid]
    connection_sql.query(sql,values, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("We got all user messages");
        result = JSON.stringify(result)
        wsServer.broadcast(result)

      });

    connections.push(connection)
```

> **A message from the client.**

```
 connection.on('message', (mes) => 
    {   
        var message_details = JSON.parse(mes.utf8Data)
        var email_sender_id = message_details.email_sender_id
        var email_receiver_id = message_details.email_receiver_id
        
              
        var message_data = message_details.message_data
        var date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
        
        sql = "INSERT INTO messages(email_sender_id,email_receiver_id,message_data,sent_time) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
        values = [email_sender_id,email_receiver_id,message_data,date]

        connection_sql.query(sql,values, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("1 record inserted");
          });
```

> **Here i tried to find the receiver id, it's not working.**

```
 var messageArray = JSON.parse(message)
          var toUserWebSocket;
          connections.forEach(element => {
            if(element.userid == email_receiver_id)
            {
                toUserWebSocket = element
            }
        })

        toUserWebSocket.send(JSON.stringify(messageArray))

        
        connections.forEach(element => {
            if (element != connection)
                element.sendUTF(mes.utf8Data)
        })
    })

    connection.on('close', (resCode, des) => {
        console.log('connection closed')
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(connection), 1)
    })

})
```